# Can I accept two &str params and return one or the other?

Tags: rust, lifetime

So I tried to make this function:

```
pub fn pluralize(singular: &str, plural: &str, count: u64) -> &str {
    if count == 1 {
        singular
    } else {
        plural
    }
}
```

But I get a lifetime error:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
   --> test.rs:165:63
    |
165 | pub fn pluralize(singular: &str, plural: &str, count: u64) -> &str {
    |                                                               ^ expected lifetime parameter
    |
    = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but the signature does not say whether it is borrowed from `singular` or `plural`
```

I can make it compile and work by returning a String instead of &str and calling to_string() on each input.  But that is less efficient, so I'd like to know if there is a good/idomatic way to do it as I first intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell Rust that the result is alive only as long as the arguments `singular` and `plural` are alive:

```
fn pluralize<'a>(singular: &'a str, plural: &'a str, count: u64) -> &'a str {
    // ...
}
```

Note that this prevents you from doing something like this:

```
let singular = "one".to_string();
let pluralized = {
    let plural = "two".to_string();
    pluralize(&singular, &plural, 1)
};
println!("{:?}", pluralized);
```

That is, even though `pluralized` would be a reference to `singular`, which lives long enough to be printed in the end, Rust assumes it could also be a reference to `plural`, which goes out of scope before the final print statement. The compiler thus tells you:

```
error[E0597]: `plural` does not live long enough
  --> test.rs:9:30
   |
7  |     let pluralized = {
   |         ---------- borrow later stored here
8  |         let plural = "two".to_string();
9  |         pluralize(&singular, &plural, 1)
   |                              ^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
10 |     };
   |     - `plural` dropped here while still borrowed
```

In general, Rust normally requires an explicit lifetime for argument and return types of functions:

```
fn do_nothing<'a>(s: &'a str) -> &'a str { ... }
```

This means `do_nothing` is a function that takes an argument with lifetime `'a` and returns a reference with the same lifetime `'a`. But the compiler implements some sensible rules to guess the lifetimes of the result type in most common cases. This allows you to omit the lifetimes for argument and result types, like this:

```
fn do_nothing(s: &str) -> &str { ... }
```

The rules are:

> - Each elided lifetime in the parameters becomes a distinct lifetime parameter.
> - If there is exactly one lifetime used in the parameters (elided or not), that lifetime is assigned to all elided output lifetimes.
> - If the receiver has type &Self or &mut Self, then the lifetime of that reference to Self is assigned to all elided output lifetime parameters.

(from https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/lifetime-elision.html)

In your example, you had two lifetimes in the arguments (one for each `&str` reference). None of the rules matched, so the compiler asked you to specify the lifetimes explicitly.